# How to optimize script selecting and creating Named Ranges?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, named-ranges

I'm working on a section of code to create named ranges of rows in a sorted Google Sheet, grouped by the value in the "offset" column of each row. I'm looking for the more efficient way of selecting these ranges. Below is what I currently have, any advice is appreciated!

```
function nameRanges(input, sheet, ss, offset) {
  var maxrows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var numRows = input.getNumRows();
  sheet.deleteRows(numRows+1, maxrows-numRows);
  var sheetname = sheet.getName();
  var numCol = input.getNumColumns();

  for (var j = 2, x=2, y=3; i <= numRows -1, j <= numRows, x <= numRows; x++, y++) { 
    var jvalue = sheet.getRange(j,offset).getValue();
    var xvalue = sheet.getRange(x,offset).getValue();
    var yvalue = sheet.getRange(y,offset).getValue();
    var start = j;

    if (xvalue != yvalue) {
      var rangesize = sheet.getRange(j, 1, (y-j) , numCol);
      Logger.log("New NamedRange "+sheetname + jvalue +" created from "+ start + " to " +y);
      ss.setNamedRange (sheetname + jvalue, rangesize);
      rangesize.setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      j = y;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to not declare your variables inside for loops. Declare them outside, in the beginning. There are also several [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) for Apps Scripts that's too long to post here.